# How to fix my clock app from running fast?

Tags: clock

I recently had an issue with my Samsung Galaxy S5 and sent it back. Verizon sent me a new one, which I presume is a refurbished model.

It seems to work okay except for a fatal flaw: the clock runs fast. Here's the details I've learned about the problem:

- It doesn't run steadily fast. It will jump ahead several minutes at a time.
- It also affects the timer and stopwatch.
- Pinging the network via a text, phone call, or toggling airplane mode, will reset the clock to the correct network time.
- In airplane mode, it will just continually increment.
- If plugged in and the screen set to stay on, the clock keeps the correct time.
- All other clock apps I found just use the same network time variable, so are also therefore incorrect.
- Alarms will only sound if the clock actually reports the time for the alarm, but not if it happens to jump past the set alarm time. (I experienced the reverse condition where the same alarm sounded twice, first when the clock was fast by a few minutes, then a few minutes later after a network ping and clock time adjustment.)

I've looked around on various forums and could not find anything useful. I did at least find a clock app, [ClockSync](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ru.org.amip.ClockSync&hl=en), that pings a server for it's time (supposedly an atomic time) not the network, and will give notifications when the stock clock app is incorrect past a threshold. If you have root permissions, you can set ClockSync to correct the Clock app at certain intervals. I'd rather not do that, and I suspect it would just waste battery.

What is causing this issue? How can I fix it?

Additional issues that are likely related to this issue is that text messages and emails originally show in the correct order or under the correct time heading, but after a sync with the network, they get jumbled up. The Calendar app seems to miss alerts occasionally. Pretty much any app that uses the system time is suspect to run incorrectly.

Comment: I have since sent that phone back for another one and the problem was not present in that phone.